# Is it necessary to have uniquie field in a solr doc? Please help fix my solr design

Tags: solr

I have a single core solr instance running. I want to store two different types of docs.

1. Basic profile for a user(s). (fields: uid : "1" , docType="profile"..)
2. The cars each user owns. (fields uid:"1", docType="cars"...)

1 will have single doc per user. 2 will have multiple docs(each separate car) for each user.

I dont want multivalues field for cars due to some design reason. I need multiple docs for 1 car per user.

If i declare uid as unique field in schema then my car doc added later will overwrite my profile doc for that user, or even other car docs from the same user added previously bcoz the uid is same. How can I achieve what I am trying to(i.e. 1 profile doc per user and multiple car docs per user)

I have just started working on solr so this cud be very basic so please pardon me for that.

Thnx for your time.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the Universal Unique Identifier to the schema.xml.

In the schema.xml file add the following fieldType.

```
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
```

Then add new field with this type.

```
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW" />
```

Finally, define your uniqueId key with this field.

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

For more information check [UniqueKey page in Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey).

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to have a unique field for better maintenance of documents.

Solr maintain the documents based on unique IDs. If you insert a document with the same existing ID, Solr will overwrite the previous one.

In your example, using same uid for profile and cars is not a good solution. Make only one of them use that uid. For example, assign the uid only to users and make it unique.

```
<uniqueKey>uid</uniqueKey>
```

Now give different id to cars.

You may also want to use Multivalue Field. For example,

```
 <field name="user" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="cars" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

And you can have docs like this:

```
<doc>
  <field name="uid">UserID</field>
  <field name="name">User Name</field>
  <field name="cars">Car 1</field>
  <field name="cars">Car 2</field>
  <field name="cars">Car 3</field>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you put your docs into the index, you could create an artificial key being a concatenation of uid and docType, if the combination is unique. Using a UUIDField of course is also a valid option, although you get meaningless keys.